# Upgrade a package in containerised application

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yarnpkg

I I would like to update a Yarn package inside `package.json` (Next.js project) within a docker container. I saw that inside the docker file we run `yarn install --frozen-lockfile`
For this project there is also a docker compose with other containers.

How would you do that? My first try was to run the `docker compose up` then `yarn upgrade 'package'` but I got errors not related to the package like I am running a new yarn install on my environment.

Comment: You should be able to run [`yarn up`](https://yarnpkg.com/cli/up) in your host development environment normally, then `docker-compose build` a new image and `docker-compose up -d` to run it.  There's nothing special about the upgrade step if you're eventually going to run the application in a container.

Answer (score 0):

When you are upgrading anything it is always recommended NOT to do it on the live/running container. Instead, it is recommended you update what you want to update in your source code and Dockerfile and then create a NEW version of the image and deploy the new image over the old one with docker-compose in your case.

That's what best practice is striving towards. If this is possible it is recommended you go this route.